# RelativeLayout with ImageView and TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with an `ImageView` on top and the `TextView` as caption.

Now I want the `ImageView` to be zoomed with gestures (that works), but how can I tell the `RelativeLayout` (which has `LayoutParams` both set to `WRAP_CONTENT`) to **refresh** and **resize** itself? The `RelativeLayout` has an *9-Patch background graphic*, if this is important.

Comment: Did you try to invalidate it?

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not have a refresh view for wrap_content once it has been displayed.. So you need to modify the size of the RelativeLayout programmatically...

I don't know your exact scenario, but maybe you should try to implement that with:

```
getLayoutParams().height= X;
```